# Sort a list alphabetically according to the second element in sublist but in case insensitive

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list with sublists inside, according to the second element of sublist alphabetically. But the result is putting sublists whose second element is uppercase at first and sublists whose second element is lowercase at last. I want it to sort it without being case sensitive. Below example explains what I want clearer:

Input:

```py
data = [[0, "ba"], [0, "ab"], [0, "BB"], [0, "AA"]]
print(sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Result:

```py
[[0, 'AA'], [0, 'BB'], [0, 'ab'], [0, 'ba']]
```

What I want:

```py
[[0, 'AA'], [0, 'ab'], [0, 'ba'], [0, 'BB']]
```

I'm using Python 3.9.7. How can I make it to sort the list according to the second element of sublist without being case-sensitive? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you wrote `key=lambda x: x[1]`, what is your understanding of how that works?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I've found it on web. From what I've understood is the `1` in `x[1]` represents which element should the sorter look in the sublist.

Comment: The way it works is that you declare, for each of the `x` values in the original list, you should sort them according to what `x[1]` evaluates to. Can you think of some other calculation you could do, that gives you the desired sort order? There are two steps you need: get the `[1]` element, and compare case-insensitively. You know how to do one; the linked duplicate covers the other. Just put them together.

Comment: @YılmazAlpaslan first you said `I want it to sort it without being case sensitive.` but the last sentence says:  
`How can I make it to sort the list according to the second element of sublist without being case-insensitive?` I guess the first one was correct from the rest of your message. right? please edit to make it clear

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I've understood you, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need them to be case insensitive. Tell the sort function to upper or lower before comparing:

```
data = [[0, "ba"], [0, "ab"], [0, "BB"], [0, "AA"]]
print(sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[1].upper()))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. By the way, I can't accept it as answer, it tells me to wait 9 minutes.